# How to enable android antialiasing in java canvas?

Tags: android, image, canvas, paint, antialiasing

we had problems to draw nice & smooth images in java, because they were jagged.
This code solved our problem:

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
```

but now we are making the same app for android, but we have no clue how to apply similar interpolation or antialiasing to an android app.

(we use eclipse emulator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **Paint** object.

1. create a `Paint` object `p`
2. set `p.setFilterBitmap(true)`
3. pass the paint `p` in your `Canvas`'s draw methods

This will activate (bilinear) filtering that will smoothen the "content" of the bitmap. You can also try to activate anti-aliasing with `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)`, but that will affect only the outer edges of the bitmap (it is pretty handy for text though).

Comment: Thank you, but how exactly do I pass the paint p and the other stuff? "pass the paint p in your Canvas's draw methods"

Comment: In `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` you can do something like: `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0.f, 0.f, mPaint)`

Comment: Thanks. setFilterBitmap is what I was looking for since setAntiAlias has almost no effect on (my) images..