# Disable bitmap filtering on Android Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, pixel, antialiasing

I am trying to display simple pixel art on a canvas, but it gets displayed blurry because of anti-aliasing, bilinear filtering, or possibly something similar. For as far as I know I have no way to identify it specifically.

Other people have asked the same question before, but the answers seem to be very outdated.

What I basically have at the moment:

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(false);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
```

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , 320, 320, false);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap , 30, 50, paint);
```

**Edit 1**

I've come to the conclusion that it is definitely not anti-aliasing since that would actually try to make the borders smooth. Can anyone recognize what is actually happening?

[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p2IM.png)

[Screenshot of the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mozs.png)

[The image after getting brutalized by some unidentified filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS9bl.jpg)

Comment: So presumably you found this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827549/how-to-enable-android-antialiasing-in-java-canvas.   Why are you `setDither`ing (doesn't that kind of smudge things around a bit?)?  Alternatively is the bitmap getting stretched / squashed / no-longer correct aspect ratio?

Comment: Did you try to evaluate "bitmap" OUTSIDE a real ImageView but using Breakpoint and ALT+F8 panel instead? ImageView usually scales the Bitmap, so verify the correctness of your code by viewing in that ImageView could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following code in addition to what you did, and it seems to work.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inDensity = options.inTargetDensity ;

    forestBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.forest_bkg, options);
```